# UIWebView keyboard is transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, keyboard

We got a nasty problem in our application. We use `UIWebView` for some card payment stuff(3Dsecure) and have faced a problem with `UIKeyboard`.
When tap on webpage's input field, it gets focus, you can see a cursor, but keyboard doesn't appear:

[Input field has cursor, but no keyboard on the screen](http://s14.postimg.org/7qjzbcr7l/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Jul_30_2015_14_35_00.png)

But actually you can press buttons and input works:

[You can touch keyboard buttons](http://s22.postimg.org/f25us2fy9/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Jul_30_2015_14_44_32.png)

Another strange behaviour is about notifications. If I add observers to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, only willShow method will be called. Also notification data differs from `UITextField`'s keyboard notification.

**UITextField**:

```
{name = UIKeyboardWillShowNotification; userInfo = {
UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.35";
UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}";
UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 460}";
UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 460}";
UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}}";
UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}}";}}
```

**Webpage input field**

```
{name = UIKeyboardWillShowNotification; userInfo = {
UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 260}}";
UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 698}";
UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 438}";
UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 260}}";
UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 308}, {320, 260}}";}}
```

Already tried any semi-related `UIWebView-keyboard` fixes, like `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`. No luck. Reproduces on simulator and devices quite often(iPhone5 iOS8.4, simulator iPhone5 iOS8.3).

One more thing: after you leave this screen, keyboards called for native `UITextField` also get broken - they appear(without animation), you can enter some letters. But when you finish keyboard stays on the screen and passes touches through itself to the view.

Any ideas? Really appreciate some thoughts about this! Thanks in advance!